# How to change this expression to date in ORACLE

Tags: oracle12c

How can I change below expression to give me a output in format `MMM d, yyyy` given the below `act_start_date_time` is a date column in ORACLE.

```
select DECODE(MAX(A.NAME), NULL, NULL, max(act_start_date_time))
```

Comment: If it's already a date, why does the title ask about changing it to a date? If you mean a string in the format you showed them rhe same as any other date to char conversion - what have you tried? Is `MMM` just supposed to be `Mon` and `d` supposed to be `dd` perhaps?

Comment: (select DECODE(MAX(A.NAME),NULL,NULL, TO_DATE(max(RCA.act_start_date_time),'YYYY/MON/DD HH:MI:SS'))... doesnt seem to work...

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" isn't very helpful; do you get an error, or wrong results?

Answer (score 0):

If `act_start_date_time` is a column of datatype `date` then you should not be passing it into the `to_date()` function. If you do:

```
to_date(act_start_date_time, 'YYYY/MON/DD HH:MI:SS')
```

then you are implicitly converting the date to a string using your session's NLS settings, so it's really:

```
to_date(to_char(act_start_date_time), 'YYYY/MON/DD HH:MI:SS')
```

which is

```
to_date(to_char(act_start_date_time, <NLS_DATE_FORMAT>), 'YYYY/MON/DD HH:MI:SS')
```

which will either error, give you the same date back, or give you a different date, depending on what your current `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is and the original value you're looking at. For instance:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-RR';
select to_date(sysdate, 'YYYY/MON/DD HH:MI:SS') from dual;

TO_DATE(S
---------
17-AUG-02
```

so 2017-08-02 has been translated to [20]02-08-17. Which is not helpful.

To convert a date into a formatted string you need to use the `to_char()` function instead, e.g. something like:

```
decode(max(a.name),null,null, to_char(max(rca.act_start_date_time), 'YYYY/MON/DD HH:MI:SS'))
```

or

```
to_char(case when max(a.name) is not null then max(rca.act_start_date_time) end, 'YYYY/MON/DD HH:MI:SS')
```

or to get the format you first asked about use format mask `'FMMon DD, YYYY'`. The `FM` modifier removes leading zeros from the day number. But with all of those, be aware that NLS settings still have an effect; the abbreviated month name will be shown in the session's date language; if you need to make sure it's always shown in a specific language you can supply that as the optional third argument to the function:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'FMMon DD, YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'FMMO
---------------------
Aug 2, 2017

select to_char(sysdate, 'FMMon DD, YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=FRENCH') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'FMMONDD,YYYY
-----------------------------
Août 2, 2017
```

Quick demo with fake data from CTEs and relying on the session language:

```
with a (id, name) as (select 1, null from dual union all select 2, 'Joe' from dual),
rca (id, act_start_date_time) as (select 1, sysdate from dual union all select 2, sysdate from dual)
select a.id,
  max(a.name),
  decode(max(a.name), null, null,
    to_char(max(rca.act_start_date_time), 'YYYY/MON/DD HH:MI:SS')) as string1,
  to_char(case when max(a.name) is not null then max(rca.act_start_date_time) end,
     'YYYY/MON/DD HH:MI:SS') as string2,
  to_char(case when max(a.name) is not null then max(rca.act_start_date_time) end,
     'FMMon DD, YYYY') as string3
from a
join rca on rca.id = a.id
group by a.id;

        ID MAX STRING1              STRING2              STRING3              
---------- --- -------------------- -------------------- ---------------------
         1                                                                    
         2 Joe 2017/AUG/02 11:03:47 2017/AUG/02 11:03:47 Aug 2, 2017
```

(Without your table structures or sample data  I can't comment on whether the aggregation and conversion is appropriate, so adapt as needed for your real scenario...)

The date format models [are listed in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212).